# How can I control the zoom speed when selecting a point on a leaflet map (with Shiny) when the user presses the button to zoom in to the point?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-reactivity, r-leaflet

I am developing a dashboard in `Rmarkdown`, `Flexdashboard` and `Shiny`. At the moment I am using `Leaflet` to map several points and I have a shiny input, which when pressing a button selects a certain point and zooms it.

I would like to know if there is a way to control the zoom speed.

##### An example in pictures:

**Initial state of the map, the points are in blue.**

[image: map1]

**Panel where the user selects the point and the button executes the filtering and zooming.**

[image: inputs1]

**In this image I show the zoom to the selected point, which is very fast.**

[image: map2]

I leave some example code and I remain attentive to your comments. Thank you.

`{r chunk, echo = false}`

```
leafletOutput(outputId = "mapa1")

# DATA FILTERED BY USER INPUT (1 point)
rbdFiltered <- reactive({
  misDatos()[misDatos()$rdb == input$rbd, ]
})

# LEAFLET OBJECT WITH ALL POINTS
myMap <- reactive({
  input$params
  leaflet() %>% 
    addTiles() %>% 
    addCircleMarkers(data = misDatos(), lng = ~ longitud, lat = ~ latitud, radius = 3, group = "myMarkers") %>% 
    setView(lng = -70.560946, lat = -33.592340, zoom = 13) # ZOOM SET HERE
})


# OBSERVE EVENT (Select a point)

observeEvent(input$BT_select_rbd, {
  leafletProxy(mapId = "mapa1") %>% clearGroup(group = "myMarkers") %>% 
    addCircleMarkers(data = rbdFiltered(), lng = ~ longitud, lat = ~ latitud, radius = 3, group = "myMarkers") %>% 
# HERE A ZOOM TO THE SELECTED POINT IS PROCESSED, IS IT POSSIBLE TO CONTROL THE SPEED?
    setView(lng = rbdFiltered()$longitud, lat = rbdFiltered()$latitud, zoom = 17) 
})

# OBSERVE EVENT (Show all points)

observeEvent(input$BT_todo_rbd, {
  leafletProxy(mapId = "mapa1") %>% clearGroup(group = "myMarkers") %>% 
    addCircleMarkers(data = misDatos(), lng = ~ longitud, lat = ~ latitud, radius = 3, group = "myMarkers") %>% 
    setView(lng = -70.560946, lat = -33.592340, zoom = 13) # WE RETURN TO ORIGINAL ZOOM 

})

output$mapa1 <- renderLeaflet({myMap()})
```

Regards
EDITED: Images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `setView()` in your Shiny events, try using  `leaflet::flyTo()`.

Comment: Perfect @SEAnalyst ! To control the speed you have to set it in options: `flyTo(lng = lng, lat = lat, zoom = zoom, options = list(duration = 3))`.

From [leafletjs documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#pan-options)